# Castle Windsor inject into method by name

Tags: castle-windsor

I have method:

```
public ActionResult Index(IEmailRepository myEmails)
```

I want to inject into method parameter unsing castle windsor.

I have mapping that insert the mapped class into constructor,

```
container.Register(
Component.For<IEmailRepository>().ImplementedBy<EmailRepository>().LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
```

but i do not know how to do this into method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't do it in the method -- you do it in the constructor and hold on to the reference in a class-level variable:

```
private IEmailRepository emailRepository;

public YourClassConstructor(IEmailRepository myEmails)
{
    this.emailRepository = myEmails;
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    // use the emailRepository
}
```

Comment: i need it in method that is the challange

Comment: Why do you **need** it in the method?  Why not just have Windsor inject it into the class and use it in the method?

Comment: this is because i have been using ninject where i could do it this way. so i do want to keep it this way (i know i can do it using constructor, but i do not want to)

Comment: If you're using Ninject to do this and it's working for you, why switch to Windsor?

Comment: its because i want know how to do this using castle.

Comment: Castle doesn't do that by default.  You might be able to create your own method injector with a dynamic proxy interceptor and some reflection, but I don't think it would be worth it.